# Browse a GCS or S3 bucket visually (thumbnails)

Tags: user-interface, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, thumbnails

I recently set up Google Cloud Storage for a client. I think it's going to work fine for them, for the most part, with one exception: The console lists assets as filenames, with no icons or thumbnails.

This is fine for me, but the client is going to want to be able to preview files the way they can in Google Drive.

Is there anything I can integrate with either of these services, to provide a more graphical file browsing experience?

A related note: I could have sworn that when I first set up the Google Cloud Storage bucket, I would get a preview of a file when I moused over it. Even this would be acceptable for the client, I think, but suddenly, my rollover stopped working. So if someone could tell me how to re-activate that, this would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this functionality of file previews is not available at this moment at Cloud Storage in the GCP Console.

A feature request was created on your behalf. Please star it so that you could receive updates about this feature request and do not hesitate to add additional comments to provide details of the desired implementation. You can track the feature request by following [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112453546).

In the meantime, you might want to look at the storage options that are available in [this piece of documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) to confirm Cloud Storage is the one that suits your needs best.